# Nested IFs and SUMIFs for numbers and text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a very specific thing I want the Google Sheets to give me, but I'm unsure which approach would be best.

| Client ID | Amount | Status | Is delivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56691668 | 10.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56411839 | 15.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56744744 | 20.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56691668 | 35.00 USD | Delivered |  |
| 56411839 | 50.00 USD | Delivered |  |
| 56536123 | 60.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56744744 | 20.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56733268 | 50.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56819339 | 75.00 USD | Delivered |  |
| 56813371 | 25.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56821738 | 15.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56928364 | 25.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56691668 | 60.00 USD | Delivered |  |
| 56691668 | 25.00 USD | Delivered |  |
| 56937455 | 20.00 USD | Delivered |  |
| 57001337 | 35.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 56911581 | 75.00 USD | Sent |  |
| 57141905 | 75.00 USD | Delivered |  |

In the following fictitious table (for context in the 3rd column `Status` I have showing `Sent` if the Invoice was sent to the client and `Delivered` if it was actually paid by the client), so in the 4th `Is Delivered` column I want to get a `yes` response if a client from the first column has paid - as in `Delivered` an amount equal or greater than 100 USD. This could be done with a nested IF function I think, but the problem is, in the first column I also have duplicate values and I want to get the sum of at least 100 USD if a unique client has delivered either all together or fractionally that amount, so I'm not sure what kind of function I could use to turn all of that into a `yes` response. Also, I want it to count the sums a client paid only if the 3rd column `Status` shows `Delivered`.

For example: client 56691668 has Delivered a total of 120 USD, so now I want in the 4th column only to show Yes.

Comment: Client `56691668` has four lines. Should `Is delivered` be `yes` for all four lines?

Answer (score 0):

I have created [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OJJX1c_E5HwEqdp0WYQ5D1jYtgoNa_I56SYZ8rcEb1o/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate. Note that I have added an extra column `Sum delivered for client` to clarify.

So you need to know if a client has payed $100 or more *in total*, right?

Let's start with that. There are several ways to find out, I've used the [DSUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094281) function. For the first row in your spreadsheet (that's row `2`, when headers are included), let's put this in the `Sum delivered for client` column:

```
=DSUM($A$1:$C$19; 2; {"Client ID"\ "Status"; A2\ "Delivered"})
```

Explained:

`DSUM` "returns the sum of values selected from a database table-like array or range using a SQL-like query".
`$A$1:$C$19` is the complete data range including headers - it starts at column `A` row `1`, through column `C` row `19`.
`2` is the index of the column we are summing up - the `Amount` column.
`{"Client ID"\ "Status"; A2\ "Delivered"}` - these are the criteria for our query. We want to include only rows which have a client ID equal to the "this" client ID, which is found in cell `A2`. And we only want those with `Status` equal to `Delivered`. (Note that, depending on your locale, you might have to use commas instead of backslashes, as in`{"Client ID", "Status"; A2, "Delivered"}`).

Now drag this formula down across all the cells in the `D` column. The `D` column should now display the "delivered sum" for the client.

When we have that, it is a simple task to populate the `Is delivered` column (column `E`). For `E2`, enter this formula:

```
=IF(D2 >= 100; "yes"; "")
```

This compares the value of cell `D2` ("Sum delivered for client") with 100. If it is equal or greater, a `yes` is outputted, else an empty string (i.e. nothing).

---

If you don't want the `Sum delivered for client` value to be visible, you could either right-click → *Hide column*, or combine the two formulas:

```
=IF(DSUM($A$1:$C$19; 2; {"Client ID"\ "Status"; A2\ "Delivered"}) >= 100; "yes"; "")
```

Answer (score 0):

simply paste this formula into 4th column:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A; 
 QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:C; 
 "select A, B, C where C = 'Delivered'"); 
   "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"); 
     "select Col1 where Col2 >= 100");
 1; 0); "yes"; )); )
```

**here is a demo spreadsheet:** **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1whdB-YOR4PdtMgpAGpwExCv9eNKTac0A9IxrlY_OlWc/edit#gid=0)**

[image]

**how this works:**

it's based on a triple query where each query is fed by sub-query. first **`QUERY`** picks only those rows which have **`Delivered`** in the 3rd column. the second **`QUERY`** sums all amounts per unique client and third **`QUERY`** checks if any client paid **`100`** or more USD. this triple query is then compared to range **`A2:A`** in **`VLOOKUP`** formula and **`IF`** there is a match **`yes`** is printed. **`ARRAYFORMULA`** then assures that formula is fully automated (eg. there is no need to put 1 formula per every row in 4th column) and all is wrapped in **`IFERROR`** formula to filter out all the noise